# How proof of Huffman algorithm greedy property starts with optimal tree T?

Tags: correctness-proof, greedy-algorithms

In [this paper](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2017/cmsc451-0101/Lects/lect06-greedy-huffman.pdf) Claim 1 states that *x* and *y* are smallest probability and *there is optimal code tree in which these two characters are siblings at the maximum depth*. In proof to that claim, author starts with tree *T* which has *b* and *c* at the maximum depth of tree.
I can't understand why tree *T* is called optimal, because if *x* and *y* have smallest probabilities, then tree T cannot be optimal because the Huffman algorithm won't build such tree.
I think my problem here is with understanding what optimal tree means.

If someone comes from CLRS this is about lemma 16.2 and proof to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A code tree is *optimal* if the average codeword length is minimal. This has nothing to do with Huffman's algorithm. Huffman's algorithm is guaranteed to produce an optimal code tree, but there might be other code trees. In fact, Huffman's algorithm could produce different code trees using different tie-breaking rules. Moreover, not every optimal code tree can be produced using Huffman's algorithm, even with an arbitrary tie-breaking rule.

Here is a formal definition of an optimal code tree. Let $\pi$ be a distribution. The *$\pi$-cost* of a code tree is the expected length of a codeword, where the expectation is taken with respect to $\pi$. A code tree is *optimal for $\pi$* if its $\pi$-cost is equal to the minimum $\pi$-cost of any code tree.

Answer (score 0):

Optimal tree means it has the minimum bit length. Huffman trees are an example of Optimal trees (in fact Huffman can produce different optimal trees using tie breaking rules) but there are also optimal trees that are non Huffman where the least frequency nodes are not at the deepest depth and yet end up having the same bit length as the Huffman one.
What makes a tree optimal is the Average Bit length or the weighted path cost of the tree, not its construction. There could be various trees of various configurations with the same bit length.
In Lemma one all it is saying is another optimal tree can be converted to a Huffman like tree with an exchange. With the exchange you can show that it does not decrease the weighted path cost.